# Nothing in the scene appears when i hit render

Tags: rendering, animation, 2d

Alright, this is weird. I have looked at the usual solutions to these kinda problems but they don't seem to work.

when I render nothing in the scene shows instead it renders frames from a previous file I had done. i have checked the camera icon thing too.

whats even more interesting is that when i opened a new file and tried to append the objects from the original file in the folder there was only one entity, the camera. so i opened the file to check and i found all the other objects sitting perfectly fine. ofcource the camera still renders frames from previous project.

[heres the drive link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F9CahtFZq7_T21MwtWiHvf-l9wDajg53/view?usp=sharing)

edit:

here's some images for the new evolution in this problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9d5i.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uBaR.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) Number 9 on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Properties panel > Output > Post Processing*, you've enabled the *Sequencer* option, therefore it tries to render the VSE sequence, disable it.

[image]

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for answering this. what u suggested did change the somethings. whats now happening is that it's rendering only the grease pencil objects with a transparent background.

Comment: whats even more interesting is that when i try to render it in cycles while rendering it actually shows the other object but in the end reverts back to the transparent background with only the grease pencile objects showing

Comment: I'm not sure what's your new problem, by the way maybe check what you've made visible for render in the Outliner

Comment: yes i was cautious of that.  so just to be sure i made a new cube just to check and still the problem remains

Comment: it's hard to say, you haven't packed the images in your file so I can't even see the same things as you, you've put a plane behind your letters and it is displayed as wire in Solid mode but it will render in Render mode, does it have to do with that? Plus I don't know a lot about Grease Pencil if it has to do with it... maybe create a new question with this specific problem, don't forget to share your file with the images packed within, and show some screenshots

Comment: yeah will keep that in mind.

Comment: i did fin a work around it more oh a sweep it under the rug approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so after @moonboots nobly helped me out with the original problem it gave rise to a new one which I have described in the question itself.

so this isn't a clean solution perse but I did get the project back on track with this. basically I made a new blender project and straight-up appended the whole collection from the previous file. so I guess one could deduce that whatever the issue is it's with the settings related rendering or some of the render layers business. anyways thanks for responding help was very much appreciated.

[image][image]